# How to access key values in an object using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array named "dataset" where each entry is an object with a key and value attribute, such as the following:

```
dataset= 
 [
 {"key":"alpha", "value": [ {}, { } ...]},
 {"key":"beta", "value": [ { }, { } ...]},
 {"key":"gamma", "value": [ {}, { } ...]},
 {"key":"delta", "value": [ { }, { } ...]}
 ];
 dataset.domain:[];
 dataset.query:[];
 dataset.range:[];
```

I am working with D3.JS and I am using this dataset to plot in an stacked area chart the alpha, beta, gamma, and delta values. How can I use color.domain() to assign a different color to each "key"?

Comment: You cannot have the same key twice in an object. Is this really how your structure looks? Not some all these key/value pairs wrapped in an array?

Comment: @Thilo: I'm assuming that each key/value row should be wrapped in `{}`..., so the total structure is an array of objects, each of which contains a key name and a value sub-array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an array that contains one property from each object in your data array, use an [array mapping function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
dataset=  [
 {"key":"alpha", "value": [ {}, { } ...]},
 {"key":"beta", "value": [ { }, { } ...]},
 {"key":"gamma", "value": [ {}, { } ...]},
 {"key":"delta", "value": [ { }, { } ...]}
 ];

domain = dataset.map(function(o){return o.key});
/* domain is now ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"] */
```