# D3 time and date histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram, date-formatting

I'm attempting to make a histogram using primarily time and date data, provided in a json file (along with other info) in this format: 2014-03-01 00:18:00. I've looked at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450 as an example, but I haven't managed to crack it. The key part seems to be this:

```
    var data = d3.layout.histogram()
        .bins(x.ticks(20))
        (dataset.timestamp);
```

When I view my code in the browser it gives "TypeError: data is undefined", and refers to d3.v3.js line 5878.

Assuming I fix that error, the next place it may stumble is the axis formatting:

```
    var formatDate = d3.time.format("%y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s");

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(formatDate);
```

Will the format syntax correspond correctly to my time and date format?

Comment: Take a look at [these docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) to better understand the time formatting. Capitalization matters. In your case here, you'll need `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

Comment: Cheers for that. Now I just need to fix the main problem...

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your data, or ideally a complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The data is a huge array in the format {"timestamp":"2014-03-01 00:18:00","allianceID":"123548678","name":"XYZABC","solarSystem":"VOL-MI"}. There's a few thousand of those in there, and I'd like to have a histogram of them showing how often these show up in each 'time bucket'.

Comment: The problem is that `dataset.timestamp` doesn't exist.  `dataset` is an array *each element of which* has a property `timestamp`.  See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22849865/3128209) for how to create the array you want.

Comment: @AmeliaBR The example you've linked to isn't how my array is organised; I only have one set of square brackets surrounding the entire array. Here's a larger/better example (my first one I wrote from memory since I wasn't home):

`[{"timestamp":"2014-03-01 00:18:00","internalID":22211598,"victimAllianceName":"Brave Collective","solarSystemName":"TXW-EI"},{"timestamp":"2014-03-01 00:03:00","internalID":22211736,"victimAllianceName":"THE UNTHINKABLES","solarSystemName":"7Q-8Z2"}, {...} ]` This goes on for a few thousand of these.

Comment: That doesn't affect the use of the array map method in the example I linked to.  `dataset.map(function(d){return d.timestamp;})` should give you the array of timestamp values.  Of course, if your timestamps are still strings, not date objects, you can also do the parsing in that function, or even better use a `value` function on the histogram layout object, like in @JamesTrimble's answer.

Comment: @AmeliaBR I've tried doing the mapping as in your examples but it never works out properly; I can't seem to make it work for my specific array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out, thanks to the helpful answers here. First off, the json data is acquired:

```
d3.json("inkmarch.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) return console.warn(error);
        dataset = json;
```

Then I specify a formatting variable specific to my date formatting:

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

I map the re-formatted dates to another var:

```
mappedSet = (dataset.map(function(d) {return formatDate.parse(d.timestamp).getTime()}))
```

And finally I can make a proper histogram dataset.

```
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
            .bins(x.ticks(31))
            .value(function(d) {return formatDate.parse(d.timestamp).getTime()})
            (dataset);
```

(31 ticks since this is monthly data from March). I did away with the d3.time.scale since they were integers anyway, so my scales look like such:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([d3.min(mappedSet), d3.max(mappedSet)])
        .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
        .range([height, 0]);
```

(Still not sure what the function in the y domain does). The svg and bar vars look exactly like the example I linked in my question post, as do the 'rect' and 'text' bars (except I changed width of rect and x position of the text to fixed values since the example formulas were giving hideous negative values).
Thanks again for the help, I'm sure I'll have more d3 questions in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the histogram layout accepts non-numeric input (I could be wrong). One option would be to convert the dates into the number of milliseconds since 1970 by parsing and using `getTime()`:

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(20))
    .value(function(d) {return formatDate.parse(d.timestamp).getTime()})
    (dataset);
```

You'll need to make sure that the x scale (as in `x.ticks(20)`) has a domain based on the millisecond data.

Comment: Tried this; got "TypeError: array is undefined" referring to d3.v3.js line 35.

Comment: One clarification: if your timestamps were Javascript Date objects, the conversion to numbers should be automatic.  But the layout can't automatically convert strings to dates to numbers.  @IronWaffleMan You're going to need to give more information than that if you want debugging help.  What line of *your* code is throwing the error?  Have you confirmed that your dataset is being read in correctly?  And that this code is not running until *after* the file-reading callback executes?

Comment: @AmeliaBR OK, I've managed to get the error to go away; I was doing things in the wrong order in the code. Now, however, I get a bar chart with 10 elements like this:
`<g class="bar" transform="translate(0,0)">
<rect x="1" width="-1" height="310">
<text dy=".75em" y="6" x="0" text-anchor="middle">3,936</text>
</g>`
There's 9 others with height = 0 and no text, it seems all 3936 elements have been put into one bin. I really want to paste some code but the `code` formatting isn't good in the comments and I can't edit my original post...

Comment: I think the problem is due to the bins that you're using (sorry, I should have made this clearer). The x scale should be in the same units as the histogram data. (Check x.ticks(20) to see if this is the case). You could also try inspecting dataset.map(function(d) {return formatDate.parse(d.timestamp).getTime()}) to see if there are multiple unique values, as expected.

Comment: How do I inspect/check these things? Currently my var x looks like this: `var x = d3.time.scale()
   .domain([0, 1])
   .range([0, width]);`, I'm guessing I have to change the domain values somehow...

Comment: Yep, the domain definitely looks like it's the culprit. A simple way to view variables in the console is to temporarily put `console.log(x)` in your code. For the domain, have a look at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent. The accessor function should be something like the function defined in .value() in my code example. I have to admit I'm a bit out of my depth here - I've never created a D3 histogram, and I don't really know the optimal approach for a date histogram.

Comment: OK so, I've had time to do some better inspection. console.log of `bins(x.ticks(10))` gives me 10 repeated versions of `Date {Wed Dec 31 1969 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Daylight Time)}`. 
console.log of `dataset.map(function(d) {return formatDate.parse(d.timestamp).getTime()})` gives me an equivalent sized array of properly formatted times (e.g. 1393821600000). That array is what I want to be binned into bits... I'm just not sure how to put it all together. Since the formatted times are just integers I changed x to d3.scale.linear and set domain as d3.min and d3.max of the formatted dataset..

Comment: (fixed)... So console.log of x.ticks now gives me 10 large formatted times which are spread evenly throughout the dataset, and they're binned successfully, and the histogram shows up successfully. The problem now is that I can't have date-formatted x-axis, so how can I transform it back from integers to dates?`.